# calling expression on datatable object

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, expression

I am tring to use Expression trees to dynamicly build queries to my datatable which currently for tests consist of singile table:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsSuperUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public Int32 RandomIntValue { get; set; }
}
```

So I have written a code that creates test expression for me:

```
 var column = generatedDatatable.Columns[0];

 ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
 ConstantExpression value = Expression.Constant(14);
 Expression eq = Expression.Equal(pe, value);

 ParameterExpression pe2 = Expression.Parameter(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
 ConstantExpression value2 = Expression.Constant(15);
 Expression eq2 = Expression.NotEqual(pe2, value2);

 Expression final = Expression.And(eq, eq2);
```

my final variable consist:

> > {((Id == 14) And (Id != 15))}

No I have problem - how do I call that expression on my datatable? Or maybe I should convert datatable to enumarable?

Comment: If you are building expression for `DataTable`, why don't you show the data table definition and the intended usage, rather than `User` class? But if you want to use `User` objects, then why asking for `DataTable`?

Comment: Well I have generated data using EF and then I want to display data in DataGridView - and I thought DataTable will be most siutable

Comment: You can bind ("display") any `IList`, so in your case it could be `User[]`, `List<User>`, `BindingList<User>` etc. Please show some code presenting the intended usage, because building the expression depends of what is the intended target.

Comment: Well I have my data object and user using UI builds expression wchich is used on data object and then displayed in DataGridView (so the usage will be mostly setting source o data grid view)

Comment: I'm asking because in one case you would need to build `Func<User,bool>`, in the other case - `Func<DataRow, bool>`. The way you are trying to build it now is not directly usable in any scenario.

Comment: Ok - It'm going to use List<User> becouse it's easier to make operations on this object and I can convert to datatable when I want to present it

Comment: Ok. FYI, you can present it as it is -  try and see `dataGridView.DataSource = new List<User>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as already mentioned in another answer, you don't need a second parameter. But more importantly, what your code is producing is not bound to a specific "column" or "property" - the resulting compiled lambda is something like this

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = (int Id) => (Id == 14 && Id != 15);
```

In other words, this is a function that receives `int` **parameter** and returns `bool`. `Id` is just the name of the parameter,  you can pass any `int` value. Thus, it cannot be used directly as `Where` condition on `IEnumerable<User>` which expects `Func<User, bool>`, nor on `IEnumerable<DataRow>` which expects `Func<DataRow, bool>`.

In order to make it usable for `IEnumerable<User>`, the expression must be build on top of a single parameter of type `User` like this

```
string memberName = ...;
var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "source");
var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(source, memberName); 
var cond1 = Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(14));
var cond2 = Expression.NotEqual(member, Expression.Constant(15));
var cond = Expression.And(cond1, cond2);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(cond, source);
var userFilter = lambda.Compile();
```

Now you can use it like this

```
List<User> users = ...;
var filteredUsers = users.Where(userFilter).ToList();
```

Comment: that works exactly like I hoped for! Thanks for both of you It cleared many of my questions! I have spent quite some time on it all ready!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there is no need for the second `ParameterExpression` instance and your parameter must be member of the `User` type:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "source");
var memberOwnerParameter = Expression.PropertyOrField(source, propertyName); // propertyName is "Id" in your case.

ConstantExpression value = Expression.Constant(14);
Expression eq = Expression.Equal(memberOwnerParameter, value);

ConstantExpression value2 = Expression.Constant(15);
Expression eq2 = Expression.NotEqual(memberOwnerParameter, value2);

Expression final = Expression.And(eq, eq2);
```

And then if your source is `IQueryable`, then:

```
var resultExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(final, memberOwnerParameter);
var result = source.Where(resultExpression);
```

Else, if your source is `IEnumerable`, then:

```
var resultExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(final, memberOwnerParameter);
var resultDelegate = resultExpression.Compile();
var result = source.Where(resultDelegate);
```

And then you can call your desired Linq method like, `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, `First()`, `Single()`, `Select()` and so on...

Comment: You are right for the second `ParameterExpression`. However, the way OP builds the expression, it's not directly applicable neither on `User` nor `DataRow`. The OP question is quite unclear, that's why I've asked him for clarification in the comments.

Comment: ok when I call result (source is typeof List<User>) I get that List<User> does not contain definition for Where (I do have System.Linq)

Comment: @JakubWisniewski This can't happen, please be usre that `source` type is `List<User>`. And then check if the `System.Linq` namespace included or not.

Comment: Where(x => x.Id == 10); - this works the one with resultExpression does not ('gives does not contain ...' information)

Comment: @JakubWisniewski Could you please tell me in which line it throws exception?

Comment: source.AsEnumerable() - this part is underlined and it tells: 'IEnumerable<User>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Where<User>(IQueryable<User>, Expression<Func<User, bool>>)'

Comment: there were some issues still in 'Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(final, pe);' - during debug it gave me some Exception that you cant get access for parameter type System.Int32 for type Models.User (unfortunetly it was in my native lang. so my translation may be inaccurate)

Comment: @JakubWisniewski I have updated my answer. Not it will also work. Id didn't paid an attention to your first line in your code.